# How to deploy Strapi CMS with Front-end

Tags: next.js, strapi

Hi there I am trying to build with Strapi and NextJS for my front-end which is going great as I move towards the deployment of our first beta I would like to know how can I host both of these apps on the same domain and also on the same server instance. As a NextJS user I am more inclined towards using Vercel for the hosting service but I am open to any suggestions.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digital Ocean App Platform,
you can host strapi and database here, and you can host next website here. (this is the simplest and cheapest option for small production apps)
.

second option
, would be to host strapi on google cloud run (it only charge when the resources is being used), but you have to use google sql service (which i think is pricey) + vercel or netlify for next js hosting